# Why are InstantsearchJS library methods not highlighting in VS

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, webforms, instantsearch.js

I am using InstantSearchJS, but the methods are not changing colors, showing that it sees the library.  I have a .net Web forms app, and I have included the CDN for InstantSearchJS in my master file.  I also have a link to the JS file and have tested that it reads my included JS file (printed an alert).
I am using Visual Studio 2017.

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="webformstest.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/instantsearch.js@2.2.5/dist/instantsearch.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/instantsearch.js@2.2.5/dist-es5-module/index.min.js"></script>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
```

App1.js File

```
const search = **instantsearch**({
    appId: 'API KEY',
    apiKey: 'MYapikey', // search only API key, no ADMIN key
    indexName: 'indexname',
    urlSync: true
});

search.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.searchBox({
        container: '#search-input'
    })
);

search.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.hits({
        container: '#hits',
        hitsPerPage: 10,
        templates: {
            item: document.getElementById('hit-template').innerHTML,
            empty: "We didn't find any results for the search <em>\"{{query}}\"</em>"
        }
    })
);

search.start();
```

I can include any other info if needed.

Thank you in advance for any advice!

Comment: what do you mean with not changing colours?

Comment: I mean they are not highlighting as the IDE does to tell you it is a method of a class or a reserved keyword.

Comment: I don't think VS knows that you included that with a can, and can only know about it from nuget or npm https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh334522.aspx

Comment: I have installed Algolia Search API Client for C# using Nuget in VS, so it should read the library.

Comment: that is something else

Comment: My javascript file is reading other code, such as an alert("hello"); but it is not reading the instantsearchJS code.  I don't see an InstantSearchJs Nuget Package either.